# Best method(s) to backup VMs running on HyperV?

Tags: backup, hyper-v

We're in the middle of P2V'ing most of the network, so the current backup method is likely the worst - the backup agent is still installed on the guest OSs, and the backup device is dutifully pulling them onto tape, one file at a time.

I suspect there's a clever way to script (PowerShell?) a suspend on the VMs, then backup of the .vhd files, and unsuspend the VMs.  This seems like it would provide big speed benefits, while losing file-level restore (might be best for things like DCs and app servers).

What methods/policies have you hammered out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular file-level backup of only data should still be used - regardless of if the machine is virtual or not. Backing up the disk file however is a great aid in increasing recovery speed for disasters if the entire guest fails.

There are several approaches to backing up the guests with scripting. You could [shut it down](http://bunkerhollow.com/blogs/matt/archive/2008/09/24/hyper-v-vm-backup-script-batch-file.aspx), copy the vhd and start it again. A clean system backup. But what you probably want though is [creating a snapshot](http://www.gilham.org/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=aab85845-88d2-4091-8088-a6bbce0a4304&ID=243). There's also a mount tool to get to the shadow copies programatically so you could actually move them off the volume as well. There's some debate on how stable the VSS-based snapshot system really is and people have lost data. It's a bit (ok, much more) involved than the approach used by Vmware as far as I can tell and is a bit more annoying to deal with.

I think there's a service pack or patch to the Windows Server 2008 Backup tool that makes it capable of [backing up the guests](http://blogs.msdn.com/taylorb/archive/2008/08/20/backing-up-hyper-v-virtual-machines-using-windows-server-backup.aspx) transparently by the way?

Also see [Microsofts planning for Backup with Hyper-V](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd252619.aspx).

Comment: If you shut down the server before taking a copy of the vhd, it is a consistent (not crash-consistent) backup.

Comment: In the end, continuing with backups as usual is going to be the practical solution until the virtualization project is done.  Rehashing backups entirely will be a completely new project...

Comment: Many good backup solutions will backup the images both ways. Microsoft's own Data Protection Manager works well if you do D2D short term backups (or long term with a removable drive).

Answer (score 4):

We use System Center Data Protection Manager (DPM) for backing up our Hyper-V machines. It's not exactly a 'cheap' solution but we've found it to be excellent.

You can configure it to automatically take snapshots at varying intervals of your virtual machines. Restoring a virtual machine from a previous time is also a breeze. We have a SAN for DPM's primary storage, but in addition, we also have a decent tape library (which DPM integrates with very nicely) which stores older generations of our VMs.

Additionally, DPM has specific support for SQL/Exchange backups. Certainly works a treat if you have the resources.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to configure this myself, however...

If you are using a iSCSI (or other SAN) device then that device can often have a feature to backup live images.

If you don't have this option you can use the Hyper-V VSS Writer in Windows 2008 server backup on the host.  See [here](http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2008/10/06/backing-up-hyper-v-with-windows-server-backup.aspx).  Or you can use any backup app that supports VSS writers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and cheapest) method is to just use Windows Server Backup in Server 2008.

[How to back up Hyper-V with Windows Server Backup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958662)

Snapshots should be used as a short-term rollback solution and should not be used for traditional backup purposes. [See here](http://blogs.technet.com/migreene/archive/2009/02/25/3205513.aspx) for a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly what you said.  Each night, I shut down the VMs, then do an export and restart the VMs.  Then I copy the exports to some other physical location.  This is a powershell script that is scheduled with Windows scheduler.  The only drawback is that you have to shut down while exporting - which is not always acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reply to the comments above, so I'll add a few general comments here.

So, in no particular order:

I rather like Windows Server Backup - it gets a lot of stick for dropping tape support but got me out of a jam following an unnoticed RAID5 failure recently.  Unfortunately, there's a hard limit of 2TB per volume if you want a block level volume recovery.  Any more than that and you're stuck with file/directory selection.  The version that ships with R2 isn't bad at all - it's not Backup Exec, but frankly, I could never be 100% sure that BE was actually working and what I want are point in time deltas, not a tape era 3-generation model.

DPM - I may be mistaken but last time I checked I don't think it had support for USB attached storage.  In a data-centre, perhaps that isn't an issue, but if you can get DPM for free on one of the MS subscription products, what could be a feature rich, low cost option isn't available.

Comment: DPM still does not support USB storage.

Answer (score 1):

I've just ran a Windows Server backup to backup a newly running Hyper-V host which only has a couple of VMs. Job ran fine. I'm just restoring to a test server now. The only downside is that I have to restore the entire set of VMs.

I saw on this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/taylorb/archive/2008/08/20/backing-up-hyper-v-virtual-machines-using-windows-server-backup.aspx that the guy was somehow able to restore an individual VM from the command line tools. I can't quite make out the commands he used since it was only in a small image. So any suggestions on what he did to restore a specific VM would be helpful if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree. I found the cheapest solution is the one that saves backup storage space in the long-term. We found a nice tool for this after a long time of browsing and experimenting and I documented it on  my blog here: [How I Backup Virtual Machines](http://stimasta.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/how-i-backup-virtual-machines-locally-and-to-another-server/)

Hope this will help someone
Peter

Comment: Not sure why that site 404's your link, but that looks good, can't wait to dig into it.

Answer (score 1):

BackupAssist is another very good tool. Sql Server backups, Hyper-V backups, restore individual files from entire guest backups, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ARCserve Backup r12.5 id the best solution for VM backups as it can do File Level Restores from Raw/Image Level Backups of Virtual Macines. Also, with the latest Vsphere Patch it sends data straight from the ESX stores to Tape and back without a VCB Proxy.

Comment: ESX?  If only I were so lucky. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [HVbackup](http://hypervbackup.codeplex.com/):

> The main goal of this project is to provide a very easy and powerful
>   free tool to backup and restore Hyper-V virtual machines, in
>   standalone and clustered (CSV) environments, overcoming all the
>   limitations that a generic tool like Diskshadow provides.